# How to fire pattern on partial match in Esper CEP

Tags: esper, epl, complex-event-processing, nesper

I'm trying to solve route-violation problem. User defines a route as series of location sequences (in exact order) that some item needs to be seen on. So lets say that correct route is (this is defined by user)

A -> B -> C

I'm trying to write Esper EPL which will fire on all route violations. A is a starting point, which needs to start a pattern (a valid location).

A -> !B -> !C

This will fire when there are all 3 types of events found in ESPER.

But what I want is also to fire when there is only partial combination like

A -> !B

or

!B -> !C

or

B -> !C

because if route is missed on B then I'll probably never come to C and will not be notified of route violation.

Is this even possible with patterns in Esper?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can see a few options.

- Register a separate statement with a pattern or match-recognize for each
- Connect each with "or" i.e. "every (..) or every (..) or every (..)
- Insert the result of a partial match into a stream for another pattern to continue matching
- I think match-recognize has some resumption options around "skip"

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions. At the end I went with the #2 option. I thought maybe there is some 'smarter' way of doing this, hence the question. Will probably look at the number #3 later because it sound to me like a best approach in Esper. Once again, thank you for your answer.